# Recommended application for converting mathematical signal to sound

Tags: sound, software-recommendation, ffmpeg

I use `Ubuntu 22.04`. Is there an application for converting mathematical periodical `sin/cos` formula (functions) to sound? For example is there a way for playing these signals:

- `cos(2π · 440 t)`
- `cos t + cos 2^(1/2) t`

Features:

- I only look for free applications.

Note:

- I have installed `FFmpeg version 4.4.2` and `GNU Octave, version 6.4.0` on my machine and  instructions or web page which describes the way of using those for my purpose is acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a file with "samples" from your formulas.
   Simple "C" or Python scripting will do the thing, unless Octave itself has means for it.
2. Install `Audacity`
3. Menu: File > Import > ... your sample-file.

---

Some Python -code to play with...

```
$ cat rawsnd.py 
#!/bin/env python

import math, sys

# trick to make CSI, ESC[ - sequences work in Windows-stupid-CMD.EXE to activate "ANSI.SYS" (as in old MS-DOS)
import os;os.system("");CSI='\x9B' # terminfo, curses, "ANSI" terminal expected

sps=44100       # sample rate, 44100 for "CD"-like
et=10           # end time, seconds
res=2**16-10        # max value for samples, UNSIGNED, < base-two-binary-max.
halfres=(res)/2     # adjust for SIGNED, Because*sin()/cos() [-1,1]
pi=3.141592653589793

Hz=440          # base frequency, at least for simple cos or sin

top=-1
bot=1

length = math.ceil(math.log(res, 256)) # bytes per sample
sys.stderr.write(str(length)+' bytes /sample\n\n')

f=open('TEST.raw','wb')
for t in range(int(et*sps)): # "t" in "samples"
  timespot=Hz*t/sps
  #
  #> cos t + cos 2^(1/2) t  # note: cos()+cos() may reach [-2,2], so scaled to half.
  #s=int(( math.cos( 2*pi*timespot )+math.cos(1.414*timpespot) )/2*halfres)
  #
  #> cos(2π · 440 t)
  s=int(math.cos( 2*pi*timespot )*halfres)
  #
  print(f'{CSI}A{s}{CSI}K')
  if s>top:
    top=s
  elif s<bot:
    bot=s
  f.write( int.to_bytes(s, length=length, byteorder='big', signed=True) )

print(f'{CSI}AValues: top; {top}, bottom; {bot}{CSI}J')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I prefer using `Audacity`, at least for experimental usages. Can you provide a link for the syntax for writing complex formula as `raw data` in sample file?

Comment: My recommendation: Look up a tutorial on python programming, then look into what I have included above - you will probably need just a few hours of Python-study.